# How to customise the installer when using gradle javafx plugin

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, executable-jar

We are distributing a Java software package using a gradle build with the gradle-javafx plugin, which generates a native application for Windows, Mac and Linux, using the task `gradle jfxdeploy`. This includes the JRE and a neat installer.

Now we need to customise this installer to:

- include some extra files like release notes and put them next to the executable (this should be really simple, is it enough to put them in src/main/resources?)
- show an end-user license pop-up upon installation
- provide the option for the user to choose an install location
- provide the option for the programmer to install some (sample) files in a different location, based on the target OS

It would seem that this is all not too much to ask for a proper intstaller. However, there is no documentation to be found. Can anyone help me out or point me to the correct docmentation? We did look at http://jaxenter.com/tutorial-a-guide-to-the-gradle-javafx-plugin-105730.html, which lists that "installer specific scripts" can be used, however we could not find any examples or documentation of these. Do you know where to find any?